# INNER JOIN para mais de um campo na mesma tabela

Tags: inner-join

Tenho esta estrutura `INNER JOIN` que funciona perfeitamente para o que precisei até o momento.

```
SELECT categorias.codigo,categorias.categoria,categorias.slug,empresas.cidade
    FROM categorias
    INNER JOIN
    empresas
    ON categorias.codigo = empresas.categoria
    WHERE empresas.cidade = '100'
    GROUP BY categorias.categoria
```

Só que preciso que filtre também mais um campo da mesma tabela, como faço?

Exemplo, tenho a seguinte linha: `ON categorias.codigo = empresas.categoria` preciso que ele também compare o campo `categoria_2` 
Como faço?

```
ON categorias.codigo = (empresas.categoria OR categorias.codigo = empresas.categoria_2)
```

Só que não deu certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa do parêntese para especificar. Faça da seguinte forma:

```
ON categorias.codigo = empresas.categoria
OR categorias.codigo = empresas.categoria_2
```

Ou

```
ON categorias.codigo IN (empresas.categoria, empresas.categoria_2)
```